# In Harry Potter, what is the name of the "cool female voice" that speaks at the Ministry telephone booth/the Ministry lift?

Tags: harry-potter, ministry-of-magic

In Harry Potter, a "cool female voice" speaks in the visitors' telephone booth/the lift at the Ministry. Is the name of the person who speaks in the booth specified or confirmed?

Comment: It's probably Alexa.

Comment: @Roberto You mean Sirilexa.

Comment: The [script](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/HARRY-POTTER-AND-THE-ORDER-OF-THE-PHOENIX-2007-by-Michael-Goldenberg.pdf) just refers to her as "Female voice"

Comment: Are you sure that you're not thinking of the lift that takes them down to the Department of Mysteries?

Comment: Well, there is the "cool female voice" in the Department of Mysteries lift too... But I think I distinctly remember in the OotP, when they go to rescue Sirius, they hear a cool female voice in the visitors' telephone booth... LOL, I will edit my post!

Comment: I think it's just a magical voice for visitors to the ministry to interact with, like the one on an answering machine or what-have-you at a doctor's office or customer service number. There's not anyone on the other end of the line.

Comment: Dolores Umbridge, voice actor and cat lover.

Comment: I assume it's the voice of Fenella Fielding, just like in The Village.

Comment: Just for info, the voice in the lift in Order of the Phoenix is Daisy Haggard.

Comment: ...whom many will better know as Myra from *Episodes*. (That blew my mind too.)

Answer (score 3):

The "cool female voice" is a magically automated voice, not unlike the voice that gives numerical options on a regular phone (eg. "For more information, please press ONE."). In both the books and the films, the identity of the speaker is not specified; nor is it relevant to the plot.

The following quote is from *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix* pages 768-769.

Evidence of the irrelevance of the identity of the "cool female voice" to the plot:

> “Whoever’s nearest the receiver, dial six two four four two!” he said.
>   Ron did it, his arm bent bizarrely to reach the dial. As it whirred
>   back into place the cool female voice sounded inside the box, “Welcome to the Ministry of Magic. Please state your name and business.”
>
> “Harry Potter, Ron Weasley, Hermione Granger,” Harry said very
>   quickly, “Ginny Weasley, Neville Longbottom, Luna Lovegood . . .
>   We’re here to save someone, unless your Ministry can do it first!”
>
> “Thank you,” said the cool female voice. “Visitors, please take the
>   badges and attach them to the front of your robes.”
>
> Half a dozen badges slid out of the metal chute where returned
>   coins usually appeared. Hermione scooped them up and handed them
>   mutely to Harry over Ginny’s head; he glanced at the topmost one.
>
> HARRY POTTER
>   RESCUE MISSION
>
> “Visitor to the Ministry, you are required to submit to a search and
>   present your wand for registration at the security desk, which is located at the far end of the Atrium.”
>
> “Fine!” Harry said loudly, as his scar gave another throb. “Now can
>   we move?”
>
> The floor of the telephone box shuddered and the pavement rose
>   up past the glass windows of the telephone box. The scavenging thestrals were sliding out of sight, blackness closed over their heads, and
>   with a dull grinding noise they sank down into the depths of the Ministry of Magic.
>
> A chink of soft golden light hit their feet and, widening, rose up
>   their bodies. Harry bent his knees and held his wand as ready as he
>   could in such cramped conditions, peering through the glass to see
>   whether anybody was waiting for them in the Atrium, but it seemed
>   to be completely empty. The light was dimmer than it had been by
>   day. There were no fires burning under the mantelpieces set into the 
>   walls, but he saw as the lift slid smoothly to a halt that golden symbols
>   continued to twist sinuously in the dark blue ceiling.
>
> “The Ministry of Magic wishes you a pleasant evening,” said the
>   woman’s voice.

The voice is not identified as to whom it belongs to, nor does the identity of the voice help or hurt the plot in any way.

Comment: Can you offer any evidence to back up this bold statement?

Comment: The automation seems obvious from the quote. If there was an actual person on the other end, I suspect they'd have a slightly different reaction than printing badges that say "Rescue mission" on them when informed that a group of schoolchildren have turned up in the middle of the night to rescue somebody when the Ministry should be (mostly) deserted.